# Does an arbitrary product of $f$ and $f^\dagger$ belong to a universal enveloping algebra of the Heisenberg algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, mathematical-physics, lie-algebras

The Heisenberg algebra is essentially the canonical commutation relations (CCR) for bosons $[f,f^\dagger]=1$. $f$ is called an annihilation operator in physics ($f^\dagger$ creation operator). Normally, a physics textbook 'introduces' $f^k$ or $(f^\dagger)^k$ or any product of these operators. This product is associative and clearly it belongs to a different structure than to the algebra itself. Is it its universal enveloping algebra? If not what is it? I'm especially interested in the link to the CCR but it resembles the question of the role of a Casimir operator for, for instance, $su(1,1)$ or $su(2)$. Is it the same situation?

Please enlighten me and if you throw some references -- even better!

Comment: Yes. It's the universal enveloping algebra.

Comment: Ok, was this particular enveloping algebra studied? I can imagine it must an important one..

Comment: As you say yourself, it's studied in any physics textbook. There's no essential difference between a Lie algebra and it's enveloping algebra (the representation theory is the same). Physicists typically don't distinguish between them.

Comment: For somebody learning the subject, I think saying there's "no essential difference" between, e.g., a finite-dimensional and infinite-dimensional vector space is very confusing. "The representation theory is the same" is good and one should leave it at that.